# Using goroutines on loop iterator variables

Tags: loops, go

I was reading that goroutines on loop iterators often result in the last value in the loop assignment being used for every iteration. E.g. https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CommonMistakes#using-goroutines-on-loop-iterator-variables

However, does this only happen for closures, e.g. with anonymous functions?

I can't seem to reproduce the issue with this example https://play.golang.org/p/lpZ-yD1mHu

When I use an anonymous function like this, it recreates the issue https://play.golang.org/p/mDa0Z6mUP8

Comment: It's not a problem, it is how it behaves (it was designed to behave like that deliberately). Whether it's a "problem" for you in your particular case only you can say.

Comment: I should have said behavior instead of problem - I've edited it to make it clearer it's not a "problem", but my misunderstanding of the behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However, is this only a problem for closures, e.g. with anonymous functions?

Yes. The difference between

```
go speak(c)
```

and

```
go func() {
    speak(c)
}()
```

is, the former calls `speak` with **the value** of `c` in a new goroutine. In the latter one, however, the anonymous function captures **not** the value of `c` but the variable `c` itself (by reference¹) and, at some later point in time, calls `speak` with whatever value `c` has at this point in time.

¹: There are no "references" in golang, I'm not sure how this is exactly implemented, but it is as if they reference the original variable.